# Find the orthogonal complement of subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ consisting of all solutions to the system of equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, where
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Find the orthogonal complement of $V$.

I know that, by definition,
$$V^{\perp} = \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} | \vec{x}^{T}\vec{y} = \vec{0}, \forall\vec{y} \in V \}.$$
I solved for the null space of $A$ and got its basis
$$\{(2/3, -1/3, 1, 0)^{T}, (1/3, -2/3, 0, 1)^{T} \}.$$
Wouldn't the orthogonal component here just be $\{(2, 1, -1, 0)^{T}, (1, 2, 0, 1)^{T}\}?$ Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the set you provided at the end of your question is a generating set, and it's clearly linearly independent, so it's a basis.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help.